# How to check field data type consistent during insert record using pdo mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Assume the field data type is varchar
When i add a integer in it, it will post and add it as string,

and assume the field data type is int
When i add a varchar in it, it will post and add it as "0" in the database,

So are there anyway to check whether the datatype is equal to what is in the database?

All i want to check is varchar, integer and boolean

Thank you

```
//get column name

try {
    $q = $conn->prepare("DESCRIBE subscriber");
    $q->execute();
    $tableField = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage()."<a href='view.php' onClick='window.location.reload()'> Back</a>"); 
    }  

        foreach ($tableField as $set)
        {$counter=0;
        //if ($set!='Email')
        $subCol[]=$set; //column name
        $noOfColumn[]=$counter; //how much column
        }


//get column datatype           

foreach ($noOfColumn as $set)
{
try{
$sql ='SELECT  s.*
    FROM  subscriber s,list_sub ls
    where ls.ListID = ?
    AND  s.SubID=ls.SubID
    ';

$select = $DB->query($sql);
$meta = $select->getColumnMeta($set);
$dataType[]=$meta[$subCol['$set']]; //an arrary of datatype



}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="viewAll.php"> Back</a>'); 
    }
}

//assume input1='int' , input2='varchar' ,input3='bool'
//column name in database = input box name


foreach ($dataType as $compare)
{if($compare[$subCol['FieldName']]==gettype(mixed $input1))
echo "ok, same type";
else
echo "no, not same type";
}
```

Comment: man, your code formatting is terrible. I tried to make it sane but failed. why don't you make nested blocks properly intended? Why sometimes 2 empty lines and sometimes none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no point in such automated verifications.
Especially the former one.

You have to implement application-level verifications, checking if value meets certain conditions.

BTW, Mysql doesn't have boolean field type.

Comment: that is implement by tinyint(1)

Comment: that contradicts with your requirements, you know.

Comment: @LeoChan the length specifier on tinyint is just used for zerofilling. It doesn't actually affect the length of the field.  A BIT field would be closer to a boolean.

Comment: it seems i have to check it using javascript validations

Comment: @Leo it seems you have no idea what are you doing. JS has not a slightest relation to the database.

Comment: the complexity is the input box is not fixed. i have to know the data type of the field (inputbox) and add the specific rule in javascript, is it possible? thanks

Comment: sorry, i may get lost. What i want to achieve is generate a inputbox that has the checking rules matched to the field datatype in database

Comment: but since i get the datatype of field in php, but i set rules in javascript.. i need to post to js? what is the logic flow to implement? thx

Comment: you can create any JS in PHP and send it in the browser

Comment: echo "var js_var='".$php_var."';";

Answer (score 0):

You could use the (experimental) `PDOStatement::getColumnMeta(int $column)` method as documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php.

Compare with PHP's `gettype(mixed $var)` function as documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: can i check "111" is integer but "a111" is varchar?

Comment: In MySQL, yes, but not in PHP. `varchar` isn't a PHP data type. It's a type of MySQL string. `Integer` is fine.

Comment: also , that is no way to check boolean in php? i will write some simple code here please have a look

Comment: As Your Common Sense mentioned above, MySQL doesn't have a boolean field type.

Comment: thanks, that means i can not check boolean? And i have posted simple code, is the logic flow correct?? thanks again, you have helped me a lot

Comment: There is no MySQL boolean. There's string, int, real, blob, and NULL.